# Как сделать градиент

Tags: html, css

Можете подсказать, как сделать такой градиент? И возможно ли его сделать средствами *css* или же загружать картинкой?

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Я бы использовал svg

```css
body {
  background: silver;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 10 10'%3E%3Cpath style='fill:%23555555;stroke:none;' d='M 0,5 C 4,3 9,3 10,5 v 5 H 0 Z' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```